# How to Add CLI plugin to Phone gap build

Tags: javascript, xml, phonegap

Hi I need to add Plugin cordova-plugin-play-games-services via PhoneGap Build.

Documentation of plugin says that plugin can be added via CLI as follows:
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-play-games-services --variable APP_ID=you_app_id_here

here is what I try but get error:plugin unsupported: cordova-plugin-play-games-services

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-play-games-services">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
</gap:plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using try and error method

I replace

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-play-games-services">
<param name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
</gap:plugin>
```

with:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-play-games-services">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="762844631792" />
</plugin>
```